# COPY GRANTS not allowed in CREATE TASK command in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is a small but annoying issue.
I cannot seem to use the COPY GRANTS command clause of the CREATE OR REPLACE TASK command in Snowflake.

I have tried moving the COPY GRANTS clause to different parts of the creation statement (Before the AS keyword) to see if that helps, but I just get a syntax error: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 4 at position 5 unexpected 'grants'. (Syntax error line number changes depending on where I put the COPY GRANTS command).

Snowflake SQL code:

create or replace task "DATABASE"."SCHEMA"."POPULATE"

WAREHOUSE = 'BILLING'

SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 */3 * * * '

COPY GRANTS

AS

create or replace table tblname
copy grants
as
select *
from old_tbl;

According to the documentation, I should be able to do this:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, even though the 'copy grants' parameter is listed as an option for the create or replace task and create task ... clone, it is not actually supported at this time.  There is a note about this at the end of the documentation section that describes the 'copy grants' parameter for the create task command.
[Note in Snowflake Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G5Z2.png)

Comment: Thanks Rich. I never noticed the fine print at the bottom.